# ExpressionEngine htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, expressionengine

I'm trying to set up some redirects for our ExpressioneEngine site, but sure to how expression engine is set up I'm having a problem.

For example:

```
Redirect /something/else /something/else/this
```

Creates an indefinite loop and doesn't work. I imagine this is because it's forwarding the whole 'folder' - is there a way to just redirect that one page.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you expecting the redirect to do, exactly?

Comment: There is an EE specific Stack Exchange site here if you want to move your question: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You say "I just want to `redirect` that one page" ¿Which page, `this`; where is the resource for that page, in `this`, in `else`, in the `root`; what shows the browser address bar, the whole URL, part of it, etc.? Try to update your question with examples to get a useful answer not based in guesses.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RedirectMatch 302 /something/else/!(this) /something/else/this
```

If that does not work you would need to use mod_rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !something/else/this
RewriteRule ^something/else/(.*)$ something/else/this/$1
RewriteRule ^something/else$ something/else/this
```